# PhoneGap: JQueryMobile updating image src not showing on device

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

I want to grammatically modify the image of a tag and its not working only on devices (Android, iOS). It works fine in Chrome/desktop.

I tried **Div**, **Span** and **Img** tags but all have same behavior.

Please guide how I can change the background image.

I have already searched no# of questions and tried options but nothing works out for me.

**HTML**

```
<div class="healthCare_heading">
    <span class="healthCare_heading span" onclick="Utilities.switchResultsULMaps('PageUL', 'MapsDiv')"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.healthCare_heading {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.8);
}
.healthCare_heading span {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/phone/1x/healthIcon.png) ;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: rgba(16,138,177,0.6);
}
```

am using below **JS code** to change the background.

```
$(".healthCare_heading span").attr("style", "background-image:url(../images/phone/1x/healthCareBar_icon.png) no-repeat;margin-left: 0;background-size: 25px 25px;width: 30px;height: 30px;background-position: center;background-color: rgba(16,138,177,0.6);");
```

Note:- I also tried **background-image:url()** and **background:url()** but both dont work on device.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the `background-image` property like the `background` shorthand property. The shorthand is `background` with the url and repeat properties like this

```
background: url('../images/phone/1x/healthCareBar_icon.png') no-repeat;
```

so your jquery would be

```
$(".healthCare_heading span").attr("style", "background: url('../images/phone/1x/healthCareBar_icon.png') no-repeat;margin-left: 0;background-size: 25px 25px;width: 30px;height: 30px;background-position: center;background-color: rgba(16,138,177,0.6);");
```

You may want to consider applying these styles with a css class selector and the jQuery .addClass() method, rather than changing the style property.

Comment: yes correct, I did try this Background property but it did not work on devices.

Comment: This is the valid css, so leave the properties set this way. The only reason it wouldn't work on a device would be because the image isn't at that path. One common cause is a difference in capitalization. a .PNG filename is different from .png on devices, but if you're developing on a windows machine it isn't case sensitive